# C++ or Python: Bruteforcing to find text in many webpages

Tags: c++, python, html

Suppose I want to bruteforce webpages:

for example, http://www.example.com/index.php?id=<1 - 99999>
and search each page to find if there contain a certain text.
If the page contains the text, then store it into a string

I kind of get it working in python, but it is quite slow (around 1-2 second per page, which would take around 24 hours to do that) is there a better solution? I am thinking of using C/C++, because I heard python is not very efficient. However, after a second thought, I think it might not be the efficiency of python, but rather the efficiency of accessing html element (I changed the whole html into a text, then search it... and the content is quite long)

So how can I improve the speed of bruteforcing?

Comment: You sure the overhead isn't in just retrieving the data in the first place? Most sites take 1-2 seconds to load.
Python should be plenty fast for your task.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I am working on psyco now, but it is not working with the newer version

Comment: profile your program and post your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your problem has nothing to do with your ability to quickly parse HTML and everything to do with the latency of page retrieval and blocking on sequential tasks.

1-2 seconds is a reasonable amount of time to retrieve a page.  You should be able to find text on the page orders of magnitude faster.  However, if you are processing pages one at a time you are blocked waiting for a response from a web server while you could be finding your results.  You could instead retrieve multiple pages at once via worker processes and wait only for their output.

The following code has been modified from [Python's multiprocessing docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) to fit your problem a little more closely.

```
import urllib
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker(input, output):
  for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
    result = func(*args)
    output.put(result)

def find_on_page(num):
  uri = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?id=%d' % num
  f = urllib.urlopen(uri)
  data = f.read()
  f.close()
  index = data.find('datahere:') # obviously use your own methods
  if index < 0:
    return None
  else:
    return data[index:index+20]

def main():
  NUM_PROCESSES = 4
  tasks = [(find_on_page, (i,)) for i in range(99999)]
  task_queue = Queue()
  done_queue = Queue()
  for task in tasks:
    task_queue.put(task)
  for i in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
    Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()
  for i in range(99999):
    print done_queue.get()
  for i in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
    task_queue.put('STOP')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: oh I haven't read it yet, but I think that tackle my problems, I thought it was multiprocessed at first, but after hearing what you said, I have to change my thought

Comment: Even easier may be to use the new `concurrent.futures` module in Python 3.2 (the concept would be the same as what you have here, but it would take care of more of the fiddly details automatically)

Comment: Keep in mind that the web server might not be happy to serve you multiple pages at a high frequency, even if you have the bandwidth for it. It could be interpreted as an attempt at a DOS attack.

Answer (score 4):

Have you analyzed that the parsing part is the bottleneck of your algorithm and not the HTTP request and answer transaction?

I don't think that the kind of efficiency that gives you C/C++ is what you are looking for here.

Comment: So how do I parse a certain part of html without losing any speed? I tried Beautiful Soup, but it is just searching for the right tag, then search what's inside. If possible, I'd like to start my in-operator search at a certain line number, but I don't know how